# Wrong encoding while calling shell

Tags: command-line, microsoft-windows, encoding

I was experimenting with a DOT diagram and tried to do the following:

```
:! dot -Tpng -oFab.png %
```

I got an error because my filename has a special character ("`ó`" in "Fabricación"):

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ( dot -Tpng -oFab.png Fabricaci├│n.gv)
Error: dot: can't open Fabricaci├│n.gv
shell returned 2
Hit any key to close this window...
```

As you can see, the special character is being changed for "`├│`".
This is with vim and gVim 7.4 under Win7 and NTFS, so I assume the filename is in [UTF16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051018/1701155).
I also assume that when invoking the shell/cmd the filename is being interpreted as some other encoding (thanks to [Carpetsmoker](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/carpetsmoker) for pointing out it defaults to [code page 850](https://superuser.com/q/269818/71885)).

**How can I fix this?**

Sure, I can simply rename the file, but I'd like to know why this happens and how to correct it.

**Update**: I just found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/682591/vim-uses-wrong-encoding-when-invoking-commands-in-the-terminal) in superuser.SE (thanks to feedback by @[ChristianBrabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt)), but it doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: I'm curious if you would get the same error using Vim on the command line under Cygwin or MobaXterm (portable Unix-like environments for Windows).  I suspect not.  There may be a way to actually *fix* this so Windows `cmd` accepts the filename, but getting a Unix-like environment installed would be my own preferred handling.

Comment: From what I read, the default for `cmd.exe` isn't unicode, but [code page 850](http://superuser.com/q/269818/71885). [Also see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1259084/660921).

Comment: Thanks @Carpetsmoker. I took the liberty of updating my question with the information you provided.

Comment: I am not completely sure, but you might want to tweak the 'termencoding' option.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Unless I'm doing something wrong, that doesn't seem to help. I tried setting tenc to latin1, utf8, and cp850. None seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

The problem lies in `dot.exe`. GraphViz can open files with Unicode paths in Linux but not Windows, unless (maybe) if compiled with Visual Studio 2005.

## Research

The code page is set to `850`, Vim encoding to `UTF-8`.

[image]

It doesn't give the exact same error, but the `dot.exe` seems to receive a wrong argument. I tried passing the same filename to the other program.

[image]

And it worked just right. Executing both `dot.exe` and `type`directly from `cmd.exe` gives the same result, so neither the Windows Console nor Vim are the problem. The next thing that could cause that error was `dot.exe` itself. My suspicion was that it just doesn't know how to handle the Unicode coded arguments properly, as not even all console commands do:

https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html

> If you need full Unicode support use PowerShell. There is still VERY limited support for Unicode in the CMD shell, piping, redirection and most commands are still ANSI only. The only commands that work are DIR, FOR /F and TYPE, this allows reading and writing (UTF-16LE / BOM) files and filenames but not much else.

I searched on the web if there is support for Unicode in GraphViz and found that it does support Unicode *files* but nothing about Unicode support for the filenames. Neither I found any reports on the GraphViz bug tracker nor posts on the forum about anyone else being interested in reading a Unicode named file. So I looked it up in the source. Here what is `dot.exe` entry point looks like:

`graphviz-2.40.1\cmd\dot\dot.c`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    . . .

/* --------------------> ARGS ARE BEING PASSED HERE */
    gvParseArgs(Gvc, argc, argv);

    . . .
```

Following the `argv` down the rabbit hole: `graphviz-2.40.1\lib\common\args.c`

```
int gvParseArgs(GVC_t *gvc, int argc, char** argv)
{
    int rv;
    if ((argc = neato_extra_args(gvc, argc, argv)) < 0)    return (1-argc);
    if ((argc = fdp_extra_args(gvc, argc, argv)) < 0)      return (1-argc);
    if ((argc = memtest_extra_args(gvc, argc, argv)) < 0)  return (1-argc);
    if ((argc = config_extra_args(gvc, argc, argv)) < 0)   return (1-argc);

/* -------------------->  HERE GO ALL NON-FLAG ARTUMENTS */
    if ((rv = dotneato_args_initialize(gvc, argc, argv)))  return rv;

    if (Verbose) gvplugin_write_status(gvc);
    return 0;
}
```

`graphviz-2.40.1\lib\common\input.c`

```
int dotneato_args_initialize(GVC_t * gvc, int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i] && argv[i][0] == '-') {
            
            . . .

/* -------------------->  JUST CASUALLY COPYING CHAR POINTERS */
        } else if (argv[i])
            gvc->input_filenames[nfiles++] = argv[i];
    }
```

And finaly `graphviz-2.40.1\lib\common\input.c`

```
graph_t *gvNextInputGraph(GVC_t *gvc)
{
    . . . .

/* -------------------->  OPENING THE FILES FOR READ WITH FOPEN */
    while ((fn = gvc->input_filenames[fidx++]) && !(fp = fopen(fn, "r")))  {

        . . .

    }
```

[As the MDSN states:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb(v=vs.80).aspx)

> The *fopen* function opens the file specified by filename. *_wfopen* is a wide-character version of *fopen*; the arguments to *_wfopen* are wide-character strings. *_wfopen* and *fopen* behave identically otherwise. Simply using *_wfopen* has no effect on the coded character set used in the file stream.
>
> In Visual C++ 2005, fopen supports Unicode file streams.

Sadly, the only option there is to rename the file.